# Dual boot issue suddenly after working for a long time - Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I have a Windows 7 laptop and about a year ago I installed Ubuntu to dual boot with. I struggled through it since I knew nothing of computers and eventually got it to work. I've been able to restart my computer and boot into either Windows or Ubuntu without any problems since then.

Now, for seemingly no reason, I went to restart my computer to switch to Ubuntu and it just went straight to Windows. It's been so long that I hardly remember anything about how I installed Ubuntu, so I feel kind of lost with what to do to try to fix this, or how to go about it. Any ideas how to get my Ubuntu back?

Thanks!

Comment: If you cannot boot Ubuntu install, boot live installer if you still have it, or create new one. Add Boot-Repair per this and Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I got it to work, if you're curious I posted it as an answer to my own question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) – a Windows update might have overwritten Grub with Microsoft's own boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!

I held down f12 as I was rebooting my computer and selected ubuntu from the menu. Then, once I was in my old ubuntu partition, I ran the boot repair that reinstalled and updated grub. I'm not sure if this was a necessary step, since after that when I rebooted it again went straight to windows. From there though, I opened an admin command prompt, and typed:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

After that, I rebooted and grub was back. I chose ubuntu to make sure it worked, then rebooted back to windows to check if that still worked, and finally back again to ubuntu. It looks like it's all back to normal. Thank you everyone for your responses. Hopefully this helps someone like me in the future :)

Alec